# Сбор PDF в интернете

Tags: pdf, c#

Подскажите кто-нибудь, как в нэте собирать Файлы формата PDf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправляешь запрос, на пример, гуглу "pdf", парсишь ответ, выкачиваешь страницы, их html-код тоже парсишь, из него вынимаешь ссылки на pdfки. Вот и все, собственно) Только зачем вам какие-то случайные pdf из сети - никак не пойму.

Comment: Спасибо, есть замуты небольшие!